# git: is there a feature to submit one pull request referring to changes in multiple branches?

Tags: git

**Scenario:** As part of the requirement, there is a need to change the codebase in multiple git repo. branches. I would like to know, if there is a way to create a single pull request addressing the changes in multiple repository branches.

**Example**: I'm referring to multiple repositories. Ex: Repository 1 & Branch 1.1, Repository 2 & Branch 2.1, Repository 3 & Branch 3.1. The changes are NOT same in each branch, but all these changes are tagged to one change request. So, I would like to know, if it is possible to create one pull request for changes in branch 1.1, branch 2.1 & branch 3.1 above, instead of 3 different pull requests.

Comment: just merge them into one.

Comment: Are you talking about multiple repositories or multiple branches in the same repository? Also, what do you mean by "change the codebase"?

Comment: I suspect you want to apply the same patch to multiple branches or even multiple git repos?

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen : added more details in the description.

Comment: @idlethread added more details in the description.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot coordinate changes across multiple repositories with one pull request.  If two of the repos were really libraries for the third, you could coordinate seeing all the updates at the same time using git submodules.  But it doesn't sound like you have things set up that way right now.  Either way, it would still be 3 pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the same change to multiple branches, apply the change to what they've branched from. Then update the branches.

For example, let's say you have branches A, B, and C all from master. You'd commit the change to master, then for each of the branches `git merge master` and push them.